# spark stream stream join error on restart: Provided schema doesn't match to the schema for existing state

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming, azure-synapse

I have two stream sources and trying to have s stream stream inner join, it is working as expected when the spark session is running.

after session ends if no new file is added in any of the read stream location then it starts smoothly but if a file is added while the spark session is restarting then it throws the following error inside spark.

**SPARK UI ERROR:**

```
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.StateSchemaNotCompatible: Provided schema doesn't match to the schema for existing state! Please note that Spark allow difference of field name: check count of fields and data type of each field.
Provided key schema: StructType(StructField(field0,LongType,true), StructField(index,LongType,true))
Existing key schema: StructType(StructField(field0,LongType,true), StructField(index,LongType,true))
Provided value schema: StructType(StructField(first_name,StringType,true), StructField(id,LongType,true), StructField(last_name,StringType,true), StructField(status,StringType,true), StructField(matched,BooleanType,true))
Existing value schema: StructType(StructField(first_name,StringType,true), StructField(id,LongType,false), StructField(last_name,StringType,true), StructField(status,StringType,true), StructField(matched,BooleanType,true))
```

**In the notebook console shows this message:**

```
StreamingQueryException: Job aborted. Streaming Query === Identifier: [id = ab5d802a-wxyz, runId = 4496d07c-abcd] Current Committed Offsets: {FileStreamSource[/src2]: {"logOffset":1},FileStreamSource[/src1]: {"logOffset":2}} Current Available Offsets: {FileStreamSource[/src2]: {"logOffset":2},FileStreamSource[/src1]: {"logOffset":2}}

Current State: ACTIVE Thread State: RUNNABLE

Logical Plan: Project [id#67L, first_name#66, last_name#68, status#69, addr1#80, addr2#81] Join Inner, (id#67L = id#82L) StreamingExecutionRelation FileStreamSource[/src1], [first_name#66, id#67L, last_name#68, status#69] StreamingExecutionRelation FileStreamSource[/src2], [addr1#80, addr2#81, id#82L]
```

src1 location json file schema : id(unique key), first_name, last_name, status
src2 location json file schema : id(unique key), addr1, addr2

pyspark join code:

```
joined_table=(
    src1_read.join(src2_read, ["id"])
    .writeStream
    .format("delta")
    .option("readChangeFeed", "true")\
    .option("checkpointLocation", f"{change_path}/_checkpoint")
    .start(change_path) 
)
joined_table.awaitTermination()
```

I want to create a spark stream stream join that is fault tolerant and can restart smoothly even if data is added to the src1 or src2 location after the session stops.

Comment: Hey cjkapil, I'm facing a similar issue. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: me too, did someone find somethign?